# I have looked at calling c# through ajax, my implementation doesnt hit the c# method when I put a break point

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax

> My javascript to invoke the method in my c# class, the ajax call does get into success method but it does hit the c# method when I put in the break point. I tried changing the shoppingcart.aspx to shoppingcart.aspx.cs but still doesn’t hit the c# method.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('.removeCart').click(function (e) {
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "ShoppingCart.aspx/deleteSelectedProduct/",
                success: function () {
                    console.log("ITS GOING THROUH",e.target.dataset.removename);
                },
                error: function () {                    
                }
             });
        });        
    </script>
```

> my c# code

```
 public void deleteSelectedProduct()
        {


        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing starting `/` only. Correct the url like below:

```
 url: "/ShoppingCart.aspx/deleteSelectedProduct/",
```

Give it try and let me know if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

To troubleshoot

1. You should remove method name and put url of page as following

`url: "ShoppingCart.aspx",`

and put a break point on Page_load event if it hits the break point that means your url is fine now you can put complete url with method name.

```
url: "ShoppingCart.aspx/deleteSelectedProduct/",
```

Now you can check whats wrong with your method following are possible solutions

1. Your method `deleteSelectedProduct` should be static method
2. You'll need `[WebMethod]` decoration above your function `deleteSelectedProduct`

Answer (score 2):

You'll need `[WebMethod]` decoration above your function in the aspx page.

Answer (score 1):

The method you are trying to access using ajax call should be decorated with `WebMethod` attribute to enable ajax calling(@Dominic already suggested that, I am just describing it as a solution). It should be something like:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public void deleteSelectedProduct()
{
   //implementation code
}
```

Or Include `System.Web.Services` as namespaces on top of the page and used directly `WebMethod`.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to decorate the C# function with the `WebMethod` which will be in `System.Web.Services.WebMethod`.